# javascript : promise issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code.

```
function m1() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var files = $('#aws-upload-files')[0].files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        loadFile(files[i], $('#filecategory' + i + ' option:selected').text());
      }
    }
  })
}

function submitFileUpload() {
  $('#aws-upload-submit').click(function() {
    m1().then(function(result) {
      console.log('~~~ success here ');
      window.location = 'https://example.com/';
    })
      .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Error');
    })
  })
}

$(function() {
  submitFileUpload();
})
```

When button "`#aws-upload-submit`" is clicked, the function `m1()` is called.

The function `m1()` returns a promise.

In `.then()` I check whether the promise has returned a success and if it is success, I redirect the browser to *https://example.com*

In my case when the button is clicked, the `m1()` gets called and the function works successfully but no promise is getting created or `.then()` is not working at all.

I do not see any console.log stating `"~~~ success here`" at all even though `m1()` is working as expected.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my promise ?

Comment: You're never resolving the promise; in the code, you never call `resolve`. What is `loadFile`?

Comment: loadfile is another method...let me take a look at resolving that..tx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to resolve promise or reject it , and so you have to do code like this

[image]

Read : [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        //code 
       resolve();
 }
```

---

```
function m1() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var files = $('#aws-upload-files')[0].files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        loadFile(files[i], $('#filecategory' + i + ' option:selected').text());
      }
       resolve();
    } else {
       reject();
    }
  })
}


m1().then(
  () => console.log("Task Complete!"),
  () => console.log("Task Errored!"),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `loadFile` seems to be sync, there's no point in using a Promise here - simply return success or failure from `m1` directly.

```
function m1() {
  var files = $('#aws-upload-files')[0].files;
  if (files.length < 0) return false;
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    loadFile(files[i], $('#filecategory' + i + ' option:selected').text());
  }
  return true;
}
const succeeded = m1();
console.log(succeeded ? "Task Complete!" : "Task Errored!")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the callback of `new Promise` you are not resolving not rejecting the promise, so your promise keeps waiting for it

You need to do something like this

```
function m1() {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var files = $('#aws-upload-files')[0].files;

        if (files.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                loadFile(files[i], $('#filecategory' + i + ' option:selected').text());
            }
            resolve("loaded")
        } else {
            reject("no files")
        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `resolve method` after your function is complete:

```
function m1()
{

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) 
                   {
                       var files = $('#aws-upload-files')[0].files;

                            if(files.length > 0){
                            for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++)
                            {                                                      
                             loadFile(files[i], $('#filecategory' + i + ' option:selected').text());
                            }
                          }
                })
resolve();


}
```